# why google search api resultcount is so horribly wrong?

Tags: ajax, search, google-api

I can't figure out this one. Have a look at this one:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%22making%20music%20online%22
Run the json code, and you'll see that the estimatedResultCount, and resultCount are 852.

Now have a look at this one:
https://www.google.com/search?q=making%20music%20online#hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22making+music+online%22&oq=%22making+music+online%22&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i7j0l2.3685.5917.0.6135.2.2.0.0.0.0.147.285.0j2.2.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.dw7rngOgsj8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.Yms&fp=9f4c4ebd74ec7e5&bpcl=39967673&biw=1366&bih=653

We get 1,890,000. It's not a minor glitch. This is a very big difference. Why is it? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help
Yair

Comment: It doesn't fetch more than 1000 results per query even in the second case

Comment: Well, I guess the right question is, can I get the right number of results for a google query in any "ajax" way?